# QSqlDatabase and connecting to .sqlite file

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Something strange happens when I try to connect to the database file in the same folder with exe. Error message is not displayed and data from the database not load.

```
sdb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
sdb.setDatabaseName("lang.sqlite");

if (!sdb.open())
{
    qDebug() << sdb.lastError().text();

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
    msgBox.setText(sdb.lastError().text());
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

But if I move the database to another folder - everything works fine.

```
sdb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
sdb.setDatabaseName("db\\lang.sqlite");

if (!sdb.open())
{
    qDebug() << sdb.lastError().text();

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
    msgBox.setText(sdb.lastError().text());
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sdb.setDatabaseName(qApp->applicationDirPath()
                    + QDir::separator()
                    + "lang.sqlite" );
```